# Showing ads between posts django ? Trying to show ads after specific number of posts

Tags: django, nested-loops, ads

**I want to implement this thing, Like Facebook showing ads when we are scrolling posts, after 4th or 5th post we see some ads, how can I do that please can someone tell me? If any video link is available please share**

Between two post like this
[image: Between two post like this]

I am showing all the post by for loop, if any nested for loops  available please share how can I loop two different model in single loop , showing 1st item of one model after 5th item of another model loop

**I am not using google ad sense, you can imagine its like I will create my own model , maybe same post model where is_ads=True be a field like that.

This is my post model-

```
class Post(models.Model):
    postuuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4,unique=True,editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=False)
    text =  models.TextField(null=True,blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images/',null=True,blank=True,default="")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="post_like")
    tag= models.CharField(max_length=150,blank=True)
    post_url=models.URLField(max_length=150,blank=True)
    video = models.FileField(upload_to='post_videos/',null=True,blank=True,default="")
    # community = models.ForeignKey(communities,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this, I think your best option would be to create a view function that creates two querysets and merges them together into a single one that you can pass to the context. It would be something like this:

```
# settings.py
AD_POST_FREQUENCY = 5 # Use this to control the frequency of ad posts appearing in the list of posts.


# views.py
from settings import AD_POST_FREQUENCY

def post_list(request):

    ad_posts = Post.objects.filter(is_ad=True)
    non_ad_posts = Post.objects.filter(is_ad=False)

    posts = []

    non_ad_post_section_count = 0
    for i, post in enumerate(non_ad_posts):
        posts.append(post)
        if i % AD_POST_FREQUENCY == 0:
            ad_post = ad_posts[non_ad_post_section_count]
            posts.append(ad_post)
            non_ad_post_section_count += 1

    context = {
        'posts': posts,
    }

    return render(request, 'your_template.html', context=context)
```

Using this approach, you would be able to essentially create a single list of posts to return to your template. Then you would only need to loop through the list in the template to display all the posts.

I haven't tried this myself but hopefully, it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply, I will try and tell you

Comment: It worked for me but there is one problem, like if there is more number of non-ads post its showing 'list index out of range', any solution to that brother, I we can user previous ad post to loop again thats fine, or any other solution , Thank you 